# Show that $\langle s,t \mid t^2, tst^{-1}s \rangle \cong \langle a,b \mid a^2, b^2 \rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I´m trying to comprehend why those groups are isomorphic:

$$\langle s,t \mid t^2, tst^{-1}s \rangle \cong \langle a,b \mid a^2, b^2 \rangle.$$

Can anybody help?

Comment: Hint: since $t^2=1$, $tst^{-1}s=(ts)^2$.

Comment: So we can map $a \mapsto t$ and $b \mapsto ts$? The inverse should be $s \mapsto ab$ and $t \mapsto a$. As a result we have an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, you should check all the details but it does work.

Comment: Its always helpful with this sort of question to state where you found it, and to show some sort of effort. This helps people understand the level of answer you need, and also assures people that you are not just after a quick solution to a homework assignment :-)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Tietze transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations).

I'd start by trying to write the relator $tst^{-1}s$ in terms of a new generator $g$ on the LHS presentation then show that it eliminates one of the other generators in such a way that $t^2$ is preserved and $g^2$ holds, with no other (non-trivial) relators.

I'm afraid there's no one-size-fits-all method for these types of questions; indeed, this can be proven to be the case.